# Tails VM Runs extremly slow and devours my RAM

Tags: virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine, windows-11, tails

I've had tails downloaded for a while as VM (I have Windows 11 and VirtualBox) and it's always ran good until one day it became extremely slow and absolutely devours my RAM. So I gave it more power and now it averages 24 gb ram but almost nothing of my CPU. I made sure that everything is updated and tried a couple of fixes I found but they didn't work.

Comment: Try allotting somewhat less that half your physical memory  (and normally not more than 4 GB) to the VM  .  Make sure you are allotting just 1 CPU (2 cores) .  Restart the VM and see if that helps.

Comment: What version of Windows and VirtualBox by editing your question. In the future avoid using masked or shorthand vulgarity.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: @John Yeah sorry got tied up with work so haven't had time to check this. It worked but I have no idea why my Windows Machine had a lot of recourses to work with even though tails took all ram I gave it.